# How to Input 2 or 4 at empty places in a 3x3 grid?

Tags: c++, eclipse

```
void putTile(int &n1, int &n2, int &n3, int &n4, int &n5, int &n6, int &n7, int &n8, int &n9)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i = (((rand()%10)) < 5 ? 2:4);

    if (n1||n2||n3||n4||n5||n6||n7||n8||n9 == 0) {
        switch((rand()%9) + 1) {
        case 1:
            n1 = i;
            break;
        case 2:
            n2 = i;
            break;
        case 3:
            n3 = i;
            break;
        case 4:
            n4 = i;
            break;
        case 5:
            n5 = i;
            break;
        case 6:
            n6 = i;
            break;
        case 7:
            n7 = i;
            break;
        case 8:
            n8 = i;
            break;
        case 9:
            n9 = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to generate either 2 or 4 at empty places(places containing 0) randomly, but my algorithm inputs randomly generated numbers (2 or 4) at random places even at places having a number already, as I have used the if statement at the beginning of the code. Any suggestions on how to correct the code?

Comment: `n1||n2||n3||n4||n5||n6||n7||n8||n9 == 0` doesn't do what you think it does. The `||` operator takes two boolean arguments and returns a boolean value. It's not a substitute for the English word "or".

Comment: Off-topic: no need to call `srand` every time the function is called.

Comment: Apart from the broken `if` condition, your code cannot act differently than you describe. In case the code is executed (which is almost guaranteed), it will always write the random number at a random position. The selected position is in no way depending on whether that position is free or not.

Comment: `n1||n2||n3||n4||n5||n6||n7||n8||n9 == 0` is the same as `n1 != 0 || n2 != 0 || n3 != 0 || n4 != 0 || n5 != 0 || n6 != 0 || n7 != 0 || n8 != 0 || n9 == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues which the comments already point out. Firstly, your `if` statement doesn't work the way you expect. It is checking to see if `n1` through `n8` is not zero, or if `n9` is zero.

Secondly, after the initial if statement, you just randomly change a position, but don't check if that value is non-zero.

A possible solution is:

```
void putTile( int &n1, int &n2, int &n3, int &n4, int &n5, int &n6, int &n7, int &n8, int &n9 ) {
    int i = ( ( ( rand() % 10 ) ) < 5 ? 2 : 4 );

    if ( n1 == 0 || n2 == 0 || n3 == 0 || n4 == 0 || n5 == 0 || n6 == 0 || n7 == 0 || n8 == 0 || n9 == 0 ) {
        while ( true ) {
            switch ( ( rand() % 9 ) + 1 ) {
            case 1:
                if ( n1 == 0 ) {
                    n1 = i;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if ( n2 == 0 ) {
                    n2 = i;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if ( n3 == 0 ) {
                    n3 = i;
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                // ...
            }
        }
}
```

Note, this isn't very efficient, and has a lot of duplication. I would suggest using arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let's see your code like the compiler does:

```
void putTile(int &n1, int &n2, int &n3, int &n4, int &n5, int &n6, int &n7, int &n8, int &n9)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i = (((rand()%10)) < 5 ? 2:4);

    // below compiler sees "number or number or number or (number is zero)",
    // compiler does not see "if either of the numbers is zero",
    // if asked to do a logical "OR" of two numbers, then  it will do the logical
    // "number is non-zero OR other number is non-zero",
    // i.e. it sees this, probably extremely probable condition:
    if (   (n1 != 0)
         ||(n2 != 0)
         ||(n3 != 0)
         ||(n4 != 0)
         ||(n5 != 0)
         ||(n6 != 0)
         ||(n7 != 0)
         ||(n8 != 0)
         ||(n9 == 0)
       )
    {
        // program will almost always execute this
        switch((rand()%9) + 1) // do a switch on a random number
        {
        case 1: // if it is 1
            n1 = i; // overwrite n1 unconditionally with i, whether it is 0 or not
            break;
        case 2:     // same for 2 ... etc.
            n2 = i;
            break;
        case 3:
            n3 = i;
            break;
        case 4:
            n4 = i;
            break;
        case 5:
            n5 = i;
            break;
        case 6:
            n6 = i;
            break;
        case 7:
            n7 = i;
            break;
        case 8:
            n8 = i;
            break;
        case 9:
            n9 = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how shall I check whether n1==0 or not and if not move to another number?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have focused on **why** the compiler interprets your code exactly as you describe. The loop-enclosed conditional assignment as proposed by ChrisMM are a very plausible attempt to implement what you seem to try to achieve.